# is it possible to pass a single id value as an object to an event in angular

Tags: angularjs

First day using angular so gonna ask a really simple question.

I have a simple event that I want to respond to a click. Currently, it is written in jQuery but seems like it should be able to be done in angular. I have:

```
str="<div ng-click='sayHello(" + global_id.to_s + ")' class='add-as-favorite arc-favorite' data-type='" + type + "' data-global-id='" + global_id.to_s + "'>&nbsp;</div>"
```

I am trying to simulate in plunkr (first time using) here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wytErhWDDu9Qh66M7JrX but I can't even get this to work.

I think this is not working because I am passing the integer value here. The reason is that as a string is because it is in a helper (which may or may not be affecting it). Also, we have about 10 of these on a single page which, again, may or may not be affecting it. I really just want to pass this global_id value to the sayHello function. Is this possible?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo (ng-controller had an extra ' and was missing the closing "). Here's your plnkr fixed: http://plnkr.co/edit/LyErnFyzjraPOumyKxJD?p=preview

Comment: thx, I updated the url. Just started alerting so it's clearly possible to do this. I probaly have something else wrong.

Comment: You can simply add the variable to the relevant $scope (or to $rootScope via a run function) and then just reference it like any other normal scope variable.